# Disable named outlet routing

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have a very simple routing module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '~user',
    children  :
    [
        {
            path: 'manage',
            component: UserManageComponent,
        }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    component: NavigationComponent,
  }
];
```

It works fine for urls such as `/folder/subfolder/part/file.txt` but it fails when the first folder contains a `()` eg `/folder (test)/subfolder/file.txt`

I get the following error

`Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'test'`

From what I understand, () are speical, they are used for named outlet routing.

I would just like to turn this feature off, so that `path: **` will match and load the `NavigationComponent`

It only fails from a REFRESH or initial load of the application, router links such as `[routerLink]='/folder (test)/subfolder'` work fine.

Comment: Maybe, encode the url ? `%2Ffolder%20%28test%29%2Fsubfolder%2Ffile.txt`

Comment: Yep,I can encode but I would rather not. () are in the list of allowed characters. Thanks